# Is there a story about Vishnu sitting under a banyan tree and seeing a beautiful woman and thus forgetting his duties and responsibilities?

Tags: vishnu, banyan-tree

In a Muslim apologist video, they say that there is a story in the Puranas about Lord Vishnu sitting under a banyan tree and seeing a beautiful woman walk by. Lord Vishnu was so enamoured by this woman that he forgot all of his duties and responsibilities. When I tried to find scriptural basis for this I could not find anything Is this actually true or is this a fake story planted as fake propaganda against Hinduism?

Comment: It can never be true, just false

Comment: Islamist propoganda.